# How do trees grow in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Planting acorns makes trees, their wood and their acorns a renewable and farmable resource. The [Terraria wiki page for Trees](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tree) has great info about how to plant them.

**I'm wondering how they *grow*.**

I planted a dozen or so in a spaced-out row and was quite surprised to see one of these suddenly sprout into a tree around three times the character height (~9 blocks). Other planted acorns haven't grown for several in-game days. I'm not sure whether other trees have grown or not. I suspect not.

**Two related questions:**

- How long does it take for a planted acorn to become a tree that may be harvested for wood and/or acorns?
- Do trees grow more over time? (If I wait to chop a tree, will it grow taller?)

Comment: You could scroll down a bit and look at the "conditions for growing"...

Comment: @n_palum But that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer It does - it talks about how long it takes to become a tree. Explains that they grow into random shapes and sizes. Explains the vertical and horizontal spacing needed. And that if you chop the tree, it will not continue to grow more.

Comment: @n_palum Sorry, but that's wrong. It doesn't mention how long it takes for a sapling to grow, and doesn't mention that a sapling only grows once and won't continue to grow once grown.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Sorry you're right it doesn't explicitly state the growth time. But otherwise: "It is possible to cut off parts of the tree, but cutting at the lowermost center tile will destroy the entire tree. **If parts of the tree are left, they will not regrow.**" is in the very beginning of the article even before that. It's otherwise implied in various spots that they grow once to a random height and stay.

Comment: @n_palum I'm not talking about cutting parts of a tree. The wiki never says that after a tree grows (in an instant), it can't grow taller.

Comment: The implications in various spots weren't clear to me when I read it. That's part of why I asked it here.

Comment: Alright. I guess I see why the question was asked. Still -1 for not really showing any effort to figure it out when a bunch of the info was below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes a somewhat random amount of time for trees to grow once they are planted. **Assuming that all the growth conditions are met** (as detailed on the wiki page you posted), it can take anywhere between 30 seconds to 5 minutes, in my experience.

Once a tree has grown, it will not get any taller, and it will not grow any additional branches. If you cut part of the tree down (or cut branches off), it will not regrow those parts.

Comment: I am sure they will continue to grow, by experience most normal trees grow up to ~15 tiles tall but initially they'll only be 3-5 tiles when they first grow. Jungle trees and Palm trees by the ocean can grow even taller.

Comment: @BenOng On the PC version, once trees have sprouted (i.e., you can cut them down and get wood/acorns back), they do not get taller, period. They can sprout tall or short, but their size does not change unless you manually trim them.

Comment: I am playing the PC version, I know trees grow because I do not harvest them frequently. From the time of planting till the time I cut them down is minimally 1 hour, sometimes even for days I'll ignore the trees to find them all more than 10 tiles tall. Maybe you harvest too soon.

Comment: In one of my recent worlds I had a tree farm that hadn't been harvested in several real life hours (probably weeks in game time). None of them have changed sizes - there are still short trees.

Comment: [More proof on the official forums](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/do-planted-trees-grow-bigger-over-time.17098/), from two years ago.

Comment: Curious that I never have short trees, I'll go test it out tonight and share my results here tomorrow.

Comment: My bad... I got distract and did not record my tree growth(if any) I'll update at another date later.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Mage Xy's answer, regarding your situation:

> I planted a dozen or so in a spaced-out row and was quite surprised to see one of these suddenly sprout into a tree around three times the character height (~9 blocks). Other planted acorns haven't grown for several in-game days.

Other saplings (probably) will not grow due a violation of rules #2 and #3 from Wiki page you posted. Because if saplings are placed too close to each other and one of them grows up, it will take 3 tiles of horizontal space efectively preventing ajusted saplings from grow due space shortage.
So be sure to have at least 3 open tiles between them.

Comment: Also note not to place blocks or even platforms just above the growing trees, it'll limit their height, place at least 20 tiles above where the sprouts are to ensure they'll grow to their limit

Comment: @BenOng: Suppose I place blocks/platforms 10 blocks above the sprouts. Will the sprout simply *refuse* to grow, or will it just be a shorter tree?